# Running a Python Application on BOINC

Tags: python, python-2.7, distributed-computing, boinc

I am currently in the process of setting up my first BOINC project and have configured the server and site to the point where the next step is my application.

I have no experience in C programming but I know the python language to a level I feel confident programming in and have written a little test program that hashes numbers (https://github.com/ryanteck/Simple-Hash).

My question is how do I go about turning this into a BOINC application, the Wiki entry on the BOINC site is very vague and has not got any tutorials or readme files on how to get started.

I know that all of the clients will be using Python 2.7.3 on Debian Linux (V7)

Edit:
I am looking for a way to run a separate python application on each machine, not spread the load between multiple devices. I will look into converting to C but like I have said above. I know basically no C code. I know how to compile but not code it.

Comment: I think I have a possible alternative of using cx-freeze to compile an  Python application that has the Boinc Python wrapper API. I would also accept a solution that uses this method or pure python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this in the end by using CX Freeze to create a distributable binary file and then created a task just like the hello world one.

Answer (score 3):

Given that I can not find **any** mention of python being directly as a BOINC client language on the web site you have basically 3 choices, (leaving out learn C++):

1. Code in python and use cx-freeze or any of the other such tools to produce your executable - Lots to learn there.
2. Use a python to C++ converter such as shed-skin - Less to learn than 1 above but still quite a lot.
3. write it in pure python and install in on a distributable VM as in the description [here](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/VboxApps).